# Unlock a remote desktop- Citrix Thin Client

Tags: windows-7, windows, remote-desktop, citrix, citrix-receiver

I login to a remote PC using Citrix thin client. accidently I pressed start Lock PC.(Windows 7)

Now the screen shows "Press Ctrl+Alt+Delete or use windows security button"

I am not sure what is windows security button and when i press ctrl+alt+delete my local pc is getting accessed.

Kindly help
PS - There are other questions similar to this in this forum , but no solution.

Comment: windows security button is for tablets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Fix Just now I tried and it worked for me :)

when you see the screen  "Press Ctrl+Alt+Delete or use windows security button"

on the left bottom conner you could see "Ease of Access Button" , click that

Select put check on -Type without Keyboard(On screen keyboard) , then click apply , ok .

Now you see the virtual key board, once you see that

**Press Ctrl + Alt in your real key board and use mouse to click del on virtual Key board (this is important)**

Then you could see the page to enter the password, 
enter the correct password and you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

For Remote Desktop (RDP) sessions the equivalent of `ctrl + alt + del` is `ctrl + alt + END`

Comment: We use - Citrix Thinclient - so this command did not work .. 
Sorry.. I should have mentioned that in the question. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Ok I see.  I don't use Citrix but according to discussion here: [[http://discussions.citrix.com/topic/251776-ctrl-alt-del-in-citrix-session/]] appears that ctrl+F1 should do it in Citrix sessions.  Can you confirm or dispute if that works?

Comment: No Joel..it didn't work for me

Comment: @mysticLife ok.  Thx for reporting back. Good to know.